# How to remove lines from blacklist file .txt using php

Tags: php

I have a text file contains this data :

```
 keyword 1
 keyword 2
 keyword 3
 keyword 4
 keyword 4
```

However, I need to remove all the lines containing `'keyword 1, keyword 2..'` which are on txt file and just leave the specific lines of data.

know how to open and write to a file aswell as closing the file, but i don't know how to remove lines / content using php. How can I remove the unneeded lines from a file using php?

Comment: Open old file, open new file. Read old file line by line and check for your condition. If ok, write line to new file. When old file finished, close both files and move new file over old file.

Answer (score 0):

This script below should help

```
$content = file_get_contents('path_to_file');
//break the content into lines
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);
//check the lines for the keywords you want
foreach ($lines as $id => $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $keyword) !== false) {
        //remove the line from the array of lines or set it to empty
        $lines[$id] = ""; //or unset($lines[$id]); which ever you prefer
    }
}
$content = implode(PHP_EOL, $lines);
file_put_contents('path_to_file', $content);
```

Cheers

Comment: you should replace "\n" with PHP_EOL - "\n" is the native newline of unix-like OSs, but not, for example, Microsoft Windows or older Macs

Answer (score 0):

if you need to remove exact lines, [and your file use your system-native newlines:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations)

```
$blacklist = array (
        'keyword 1',
        'keyword 2' 
);
file_put_contents ( 'file.txt', implode ( PHP_EOL, array_diff ( file ( 'file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ), $blacklist ) ) );
```

but if you, as you said, need to find lines containing, instead of exact lines, or your textfile does not use system-native newlines, it gets more complicated:

```
$blacklist = array (
        'keyword 1',
        'keyword 2' 
);
$lines = file ( 'file.txt' );
foreach ( $lines as $key => $line ) {
    foreach ( $blacklist as $black ) {
        if (false !== strpos ( $line, $black )) {
            unset ( $lines [$key] );
            break;
        }
    }
}
file_put_contents ( 'file.txt', $lines );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use php function `file(...)` to read file (all lines as array). And use `in_array` to find out if given line match one of Your keywords (I assume that whole line have to match keyword). Function `trim()` is used to remove '\n' from input line.

```
 $linesToRemove = array('keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 3');
 $lines = file('file.txt');
 foreach($lines as $key => $line)
 {
     if (in_array(trim($line), $linesToRemove))
         unset($lines[$key]);
 }
 file_put_contents('file2.txt', implode("", $lines));
```

Comment: this would detect exact lines, but not lines containing a blacklisted phrase. this would not detect `:keyword 1` because of the :

Comment: @hanshenrik As I wrote in my answer I assumed that whole line have to match keyword. Besides asker show example which suggest that it is what he wants (one line = one keyword).